# How do i call javascript class from another class and push(append) values in the array that is there?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, class, form-data

I have the following two classes in javascript, FormsHolder and AdditionalValues. I want to loop through the array in Additional values class and append them into the formData in the FormsHolder class.

I have simplified the issue to make it understandable but the logic is exactly what i need to resolve.

```
class FormsHolder{
  assembleForms(){    
    const formdata = new FormData;    
  }        
}

class AdditionalValues{    
  arrayValues(){
    const arrys = [1,2,3,4];    
    for (const arry of arrys) {
      // i want to push(append) this array to the formdata array(object) in the FormsHolder class    
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `formdata` as a global variable, like this:

```
var formdata;

class FormsHolder{
  assembleForms(){
    formdata = new FormData;
  }
}

class AdditionalValues{
  arrayValues(){
    const arrys = [1,2,3,4];

    // creating FormData object
    new FormsHolder().assembleForms();

    for (const arry of arrys) {
      formdata.append('item', arry);
    }
  }
}

new AdditionalValues().arrayValues();
```

---

Or you can define `AdditionalValues` class which inferits to `FormsHolder` class:

```
class FormsHolder{
  assembleForms(){
    this.formdata = new FormData;
  }
}

class AdditionalValues extends FormsHolder {
  arrayValues(){
    const arrys = [1,2,3,4];

    // creating FormData object
    super.assembleForms();

    for (const arry of arrys) {
      this.formdata.append('item', arry);
    }
  }
}

new AdditionalValues().arrayValues();
```

Comment: Tan what if the FormsHolder accepts a parameter like this one Class FormHolder{ constructor(formValues){
            this.formValues = new FormData(formValues);
            
          }}